# HttpWebRequest and Transfer-Encoding

Tags: c#, http, chunked-encoding

`HttpWebRequest` is used to download files from ASP.NET site with basic authentication. Everything works fine in many cases, but some proxies make answer chunked and `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()` throws an exception if answer with `401` status code is chunked. The exception is:

```
    System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation.  
    Section=ResponseStatusLine
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
Trace of answer is:<pre>
"HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required\r\nDate: Fri, 26 Jun 2009 04:45:18 GMT\r\nServer: Microsoft-IIS/6.0\r\nX-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\nX-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727\r\nWWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"iis-server\"\r\nCache-Control: private\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\nVia: 1.1 server\r\nKeep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nContent-Language: en\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n
```

I made test and found out that `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is the only one reason of exception. Is this bug of .NET Framework 2.0 or there any RFC says that 401 answer shouldn't be chunked?

Comment: Does this problem occur on specific proxies or on specific files?

Answer (score 1):

I actually think the error isn't that Chunked Transfer Encoding (CTE) isn't allowed, I think it's that the server is doing the CTE incorrectly. If you look at the response body, it's looking like this:

```
Language: en \r\n
\r\n
0 \r\n
\r\n
0 \r\n
\r\n
```

If you notice, there are two 0 length chunks in the response body. The CTE RFC requires that the last chunk of a message be a 0 length chunk, and, by extension, no previous chunk can be of zero length. In this message, you have 0 zero length chunks which is a protocol violation of CTE.

This is akin to setting a content length header for a message and then transmitting more data than is allowed by that content length header.